# Growing InputField list in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I need to implement input fields in unity which will be added on the fly as per the elements in a list. It should increase as per the objects present in a map "m_myClassMap".

Also, is it possible to fetch the position, layout settings ( i.e. x,y,z coordinates) of the existing Inputfields? I want these info to calculate the position of new inputfield.[image: Something like this just growing as per the map size on the fly]

For e.g.

```
 List<InputField> inputFieldList = new List<InputField>();

 foreach (MyClass myClassObj in m_myClassMap.Values)
 {
        // code below is just statement and is syntactically wrong
        InputField newInputField = new InputField();
        // Add properties like size or layout
        // set the text
        inputFieldList.Text = myClassObj.getInputBoxString();
        inputFieldList.Add(newInputField );
 }
```

I am not sure if its even possible..Any help will be welcome :)

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most robust thing to do here would be to use a layout group. This method plenty of well tested functionality.

Firstly add a a parent object. And add a `Vertical Layout Group` component to it. I've shown the hierarchy below by adding a Red panel to the blue panel. On the red panel is the `Vertical Layout Group`.

[image]

In this example I've used the inspector to manually add 4 input fields. Note the layout here is all automatic. I've included the settings on this particular input field below, you'll be able to experiment in the inspector and very quickly see what impact the various options have.

[image]

Now for your particular solution, you want to add the items programatically rather than through the inspector. For this you'll want to create a GameObject with a reference to the object holding the layout group.

### Programatic Creation

The below code will add a list of prefabs to a class. (In this case the parent class should contain the `Vertical Layout Group` component)

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI; 

public class LayoutGroupExample : MonoBehaviour {

    public GameObject layoutObject; 
    public GameObject inputFieldPrefab;     

    void AddInputFields(){
        var inputFieldList = new List<string>(){"First Name", "Last Name", "Email"}; 

        foreach(var fieldName in inputFieldList){
            GameObject go = GameObject.Instantiate(inputFieldPrefab); 
            go.name = fieldName; 
            go.transform.SetParent(layoutObject.transform); 
            var inputField = go.AddComponent<InputField>(); 
        }
    }
}
```

In the inspector assign the object containing the layout group to the `layoutObject` field.

Assign a prefab (which should be an `Input Field` object) to the `inputFieldPrefab` field)

[image]

Comment: Thanks! The answer is very thorough and looks perfect! I will try your approach :)

Comment: Great! I didn't get around to adding how to access the X/Y coordinates for manipulating the items manually (It will be a property inside the RectTransform component of the object). I can add that if necessary. Auto layout is fantastic for stuff like this though.